# are clocks always wrong?

Tags: time

So I was sitting thinking earlier and I remembered an experiment  that I heard a couple days back about how scientists put a stop watch on a jet and it had a different time then one on earth because of speed and I also heard that quartz almost go as fast as light so wouldn't they have they same effect on a clock though I am just thinking this all I have no proof I wanted to know if what I thought had any truth behind it

Comment: You are thinking of the [Hafele-Keating experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele–Keating_experiment).

Comment: You need atomic clocks for that experiment; quartz clocks are sufficiently accurate.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "that quartz almost go as fast as light"? This sounds like a likely conflation of a concept not relevant here, because so far nobody has accelerated a quartz clock to anywhere near the speed of light.

Comment: I haven't looked it up yet, but in one of the plenary talks at APS this morning it was mentioned that there has been a recent measurement of the gravitational time dilation over ***80 cm*** near the surface of the Earth. *::boggle::*

Comment: The best proof is GPS satellites orbiting around the Earth right now, they are using the same clock as on Earth however do note that the clock used on these fast moving satellites needs to be calibrated every now and then otherwise your GPS in your car will reflect incorrectly your current location.

Comment: @dmckee That is correct. As of 2010 [this was possible with height differences as small as 30cm](http://www.nist.gov/public_affairs/releases/aluminum-atomic-clock_092310.cfm). Not sure what the current record is - or whether it's even worth trying anymore. 30cm is definitely smaller than the uncertainty in the geoid altitude difference between, say, Boulder and Teddington, and probably also smaller than the variation of the geoid altitude of Boulder over timescales on the order of years. ::boggle:: indeed!

Comment: Clocks are instruments for measuring relative time - the only point is to make sure that two people can coordinate in time. So, as long as your clock shows the same time as the clocks you care about (e.g. railway station clock, school clock, whatever else you need to coordinate with), they are "right", even if everyone else agrees they're not. On this scale, relativistic effects are way too low to matter. On the other hand, GPS *does* care - but then again, we just do a simple correction, and we can coordinate just fine again - the clock is "right", we just need to change the units :)

Comment: *"Even a stopped clock is right twice a day"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in a sense, clocks are always wrong, namely in the sense that finding two that "agree" by continuously always showing the exact same time would require a very peculiar arrangement, crucially involving the observer's speed and position relative to the clocks! However, physicists have adopted another sense of what being simultaneous (or clocks agreeing) means.

If events (such as different clocks showing any given time) are close enough in time (relative to their spacial separation) such that simply choosing from what frame of reference to look at them can determine which happens first, these events have space-like separation. This is the (relaxed) concept of occuring simultaneous that we must adopt to be compatible with relativity. On the other hand, we can continue to call some events definitely earlier than others. That is possible with any pair of events that are sufficiently close enough in space (for their time difference) such that information, at the speed of light, can travel between them within the observed time difference. If your clocks are this far off, at least one of them is wrong and needs adjustment! Exactly how much depends on the observer, but each observer would produce an adjustment such that all observers will agree that the new separation is space-like, not time-like.

Answer (score 3):

[The experiment is real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment). If you take an atomic clock that is accurate and stable enough and you fly it around the world, it will disagree with an identical clock that has remained on the ground. This is because of the combination of two effects:

- relativistic time dilation, which means that any clock that moves will run more slowly compared to one that's stationary, and
- gravitational time dilation, which means that clocks further down a gravitational potential well will run more slowly than clocks further up in the well.

These effects partially cancel out, and the gravitational time dilation ends up winning. The clock on the plane appears to run faster; that is, it is ahead of the one on the ground when they are reunited.

This is not a problem with clocks being wrong - this is just how time itself behaves. When relativity theory says "everything is relative" it's this sort of thing that's at stake. Time runs faster or slower depending on where you are in gravity fields and on how you are moving compared to other observers.